# Check if a value is between other values(properties) in an object with the object being in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to check if a value is between object values with the object being in an array. 
The aim is to try to see if a start and end `unix` time is between other time sessions . This offers a simpler way of asking the question

EXPECTED :

The code below should return `true` because the values `7` and `9` aren't in any of the objects of the values.

Values like `newStart = 4` to `newEnd = 5`should return `false`

Values like `newStart = 5` to `newEnd = 11` should return a `false`

```
let newStart = 7
let newEnd = 9

const bookedValues = [{start:4,end:6},{start:10,end:12}]

const isValidStart = 
      bookedValues.some(booking => newStart < booking.start && newStart > booking.end)
const isValidEnd = 
      bookedValues.some(booking =>  newEnd < booking.start && newEnd > booking.end)


console.log(isValidStart) //returns false
console.log(isValidEnd) //returns false
```

Comment: To me, it's still super confused. Please share some more input-expected out examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works the way it should.
If we consider the `array.some` method

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. If one element does pass return `true` else `false`

instead, use the `array.every` method, if you want to consider the boolean status of both items in the array

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. If all elements pass return `true` else if only some or no element passes return `false`

in both your some methods, neither object in the array passes the function and `false` is returned because no variable (number) can be greater and lesser than a range at the same time, so use `OR` operator instead. Since if a number is less than the beginning of a range or greater than the end of the range it isn't in the range.

```js
let newStart = 7
let newEnd = 9
let bookedValues = [{start:4,end:6},{start:10,end:12}]

 let isValidStart = 
      bookedValues.every(booking => newStart < booking.start || newStart > booking.end)
 let isValidEnd = 
      bookedValues.every(booking =>  newEnd < booking.start || newEnd > booking.end)


console.log(isValidStart) //doesn't return false
console.log(isValidEnd) //doesn't return false
```

Comment: While using your code having `newStart` as `5` returns `true` and it should return `false` because `5` is between the first object in the array (`4` and `6`)

Comment: it returns true because although it is between the first object in the array (4 and 6), it isn't between the second. that's the way `.some` works, but if you want the value to be true only when it passes all the items in the array, you can use `.every` and I will edit my code for that, you can test it with as many cases as you like